# Проблема с загрузкой аудио vk api python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

```
import vk_api
```

from vk_api import VkApi,VkUpload

```
service_session = vk_api.VkApi(login='login', password='passwird', app_id=2685278)
service_session.auth(token_only=True)

a_upload = VkUpload(service_session)


audio_file = open('507634744.mp3','rb')
audio_list = a_upload.audio(audio_file,artist='Артист',title='голосовое сообщение')
print(audio_list)
```

Выдаёт ошибку:

```
    G:\Документы\WORK\Python\ВК\ShkololoBot>bot.py
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Decart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Decart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "G:\Документы\WORK\Python\ВК\ShkololoBot\bot.py", line 356, in onNewMsg
    audio_list = a_upload.audio(audio = audio_file,artist='Voice message',title='Голосовое сообщение')
  File "C:\Users\Decart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\upload.py", line 296, in audio
    return self.vk.audio.save(**response)
  File "C:\Users\Decart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 681, in __call__
    return self._vk.method(self._method, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Decart\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\vk_api\vk_api.py", line 646, in method
    raise error
vk_api.exceptions.ApiError: [15] Access denied: filename is incorrect
```

Если вместо file-like объекта оставить путь к файлу, то ошибка будет такой же. mp3 файл не поврежден и путь к нему указан правильно

В чём проблема?

Изменено: Смог решить проблему. Оказывается, нужно чтобы аудио длилось хотя бы 5 секунд